# How to remove column bottom space in divid builder

Tags: divi

whenever i take any column in divi it's always giving some bottom spaces automatically.I tried to remove this with margin and padding 0.But its did not work for me

I made the margin and padding 0 but it did not work for me
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.